# SQL-SERVER-2008 native Query Issue

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

```
Integer count=0;

Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
SQLQuery countNativeSQLQuery = session.createSQLQuery(listQuery);

count = Integer.parseInt(countNativeSQLQuery.uniqueResult().toString());
```

Returing me the unique result with SQL-SERVER-2014

But the same query throws an exception:

> SQLGrammerException: Invalid object name 'dgcontroller.dg_regex_patterns' for SQL-SERVER-2008

But if i append database name before the schema name in the query e.g. `dg.dgcontroller.dg_regex_patterns` it returns the result.

Why this is happening Is this some kind of sql-server version issue?

Comment: Please post your query here.

Comment: your default database in the connection string may not be dg. can you check?